# How do I remove video files that are stuck on the applications/places toolbar?

Tags: 12.04, unity

Moving some video files around I mistakenly pushed them onto the applications/places toolbar. There they stay. I can't get rid of them. (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

/home/peter/Pictures/Screenshot from 2013-04-12 13:33:56.png

Comment: An image of this would help ;-)

Comment: /home/peter/Pictures/Screenshot from 2013-04-12 13:33:56.png

Comment: Welcome to AU. I notice that you have posted a link to the *local* location of your screenshot, and its entirely useless to us. You might want to upload your image to imgur.com instead, and add the link so someone with higher rep can update your question.

Answer (score 1):

I beleive you are talking about the launcher.

Right-click the icon you want.

[image: Launcher]

Click 'Remove from launcher'.

It should dissapear.

### The top bar

Right-click the menu bar. Click 'Edit Menu's...'

Find the file you want and delete it.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: No, I don't mean the launcher.  I mean the application/places tool bar. One of these files is sitting right beside Places.  The other 2 are beside the battery icon.

Comment: Can you grab a screen-shot and edit your post?

Comment: @PeterMaurer - See edit.